# Concatenating and Filtering text in Excel Table

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, concatenation

Okay, here's the situation:

I have a table in Excel with 15 columns.

Three of those columns relate to a document ID for scanned PDFs. These document IDs go more or less like this:

```
PREFIX 00001 - PREFIX 00008
PREFIX 00008 - PREFIX 00010
```

These are broken up in the table like this:

```
PREFIX | DOCSTART | DOCEND
--------------------------
PREFIX |  00001   |  00008
PREFIX |  00008   |  00010
```

The problem is that sometimes documents have more than one PREFIX (even though ID remains constant) and also some "Rejected" strings. Instead of generating a new row, the system that exported this inserted a semicolon with the other values. So we have:

```
PREFIX |  00001   |  00008 |
PREFIX |  00008   |  00010 |
PREFIX; PREFIX1; PREFIX2 |  00011; 00011; 00011 | 00015; 00015; 00015 |
PREFIX; Rejected | 00016; Rejected | 00020; Rejected |
Rejected; PREFIX | Rejected; 00021  | Rejected; 00022 |
```

COMMA DELIMITED EXEMPLAR

```
PREFIXCODE,DOCSTART,DOCEND
PREFIX; <Non-Production>; <Non-Production>; <Non-Production>; <Non-Production>,12345; <Non-Production>; <Non-Production>; <Non-Production>; <Non-Production>,12445; <Non-Production>; <Non-Production>; <Non-Production>; <Non-Production>
<Rejected>; PREFIX,<Rejected>; 2124,<Rejected>; 2125
PREFIX,2477,2484
PREFIX,2488,2495
<Rejected>; PREFIX; <Non-Production>,<Rejected>; 208181; <Non-Production>,<Rejected>; 208082; <Non-Production>
<Rejected>; PREFIX,<Rejected>; 20845482,<Rejected>; 20845482
<Rejected>; PREFIX; PREFIX2,<Rejected>; 40502; 40502,<Rejected>; 40510; 40510
```

I need to get only one series (the standard "PREFIX" series) into one column. I can CONCATENATE() the stuff that's already normalized easy enough, but absent a brute-force attack, I'm not sure the best way to get rid of the PREFIX1, PREFIX2, and Rejected series when I concatenate everything.

The good thing is that I can pick any series of the Prefix, Prefix1, and Prefix2 values, as one is as good as another for this task, and I can get rid of the "Rejected" string entirely without looking back. (This will be for review by someone who apparently likes to have this stuff in a table but also have printed copies.)

Absent a brute-force attack involving filters and replace, is there a more elegant way to do this that I've missed?  (I can import into Access and attack it with SQL if that helps...)

I'm going to run into this issue repeatedly over the next few weeks, and these tables typically have anywhere from 100 to 1000 rows, so I need something to make this more efficient.....

Thanks.

Comment: Having a hard time understanding the exact table structure. Can you post a comma or pipe delim set of rows along with the expected output? Seems like you could solve this with a combination of CONCAT, SEARCH and IF in Excel but hard to say without seeing a whole example.

Comment: Sure - added a comma-delimited dummy exemplar.

Comment: So in that example a valid output would be a column containing: 
2477
2488

?

Comment: Valid final result would be:
    "PREFIX 2477-2488"

Comment: I think i understand. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming the first PREFIX instance occurs in cell A4 you could use a formula like this to get a column of all the prefixes.
    =IF(A4="PREFIX",B4,"")

That will give you the value for column B everywhere column A has a value of PREFIX. Drag that down your rows to get the values Then use a combination of concatenate and/or transpose to get you your list of values into the format you need to deliver.

Hopefully i've understood the data.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up finishing the current task with a combination of filtering and find/replace. Is there a way I could use the IF function to get rid of text not meeting the criteria? Like IF A4="PREFIX", truncate all other characters from the cell?

Comment: You can nest other functions in the true and false (2nd and 3rd arguments) to the if() function  and could possible make that work using the replace() function. Best bet is probably Access and a little sql if you need to run this regularly.